# Serve multiple Django projects from the same domain, routing using paths not subdomains

Tags: django, nginx

I would like to serve "app1" and "app2" from the same domain using paths to route the app:

https://exampe.com/app1/ and https://exampe.com/app2/

Normally I would do this using subdomains, but this is an attempt to give a more seamless experience for the user - so it all looks like one app ( app1 and app2 have the same header and footer)

This is not possible with DNS, but perhaps there is an nginx or other solution?

Comment: When you say "app", do you mean "project"? Are these completely separate code bases, database etc?

Comment: I mean "project". they are indeed completely separate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WSGIScriptAlias option using Apache2
This is how I am hosting four Django projects on my localhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #My site Name

    ServerName localhost

#Demon process for multiple virtual hosts
    WSGIDaemonProcess subzero python-home=/var/www/env1 python-path=/var/www/env1/subzero threads=5


    #Pointing wsgi script to config file
    WSGIScriptAlias /subzero /var/www/env1/subzero/subzero/wsgi.py

    WSGIProcessGroup subzero
 #Your static files location
   Alias /subzero/static/ "/var/www/env1/subzero/static/"
     <Location "/media">
        SetHandler None
   </Location>
   <LocationMatch "\.(jpg|gif|png|js|css)$">
       SetHandler None
   </LocationMatch>
   <Directory /var/www/env1/subzero >
       WSGIProcessGroup subzero
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
   </Directory>

  #Demon process for multiple virtual hosts
    WSGIDaemonProcess gastronomy python-home=/var/www/env1 python-path=/var/www/env1/gastronomy threads=5


    #Pointing wsgi script to config file
    WSGIScriptAlias /gastronomy /var/www/env1/gastronomy/gastronomy/wsgi.py
    WSGIProcessGroup gastronomy
 #Your static files location
   Alias /gastronomy/static/ "/var/www/env1/gastronomy/static/"
     <Location "/media">
        SetHandler None
   </Location>
   <LocationMatch "\.(jpg|gif|png|js|css)$">
       SetHandler None
   </LocationMatch>
   <Directory /var/www/env1/gastronomy >
       WSGIProcessGroup gastronomy
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
   </Directory>



  #Demon process for multiple virtual hosts
    WSGIDaemonProcess astronomy python-home=/var/www/env1 python-path=/var/www/env1/astronomy threads=5


    #Pointing wsgi script to config file
    WSGIScriptAlias /astronomy /var/www/env1/astronomy/astronomy/wsgi.py
    WSGIProcessGroup astronomy

    #Your static files location
   Alias /astronomy/static/ "/var/www/env1/astronomy/static/"
     <Location "/media">
        SetHandler None
   </Location>
   <LocationMatch "\.(jpg|gif|png|js|css)$">
       SetHandler None
   </LocationMatch>
   <Directory /var/www/env1/astronomy >
       WSGIProcessGroup astronomy
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
   </Directory>


  #Demon process for multiple virtual hosts
    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-home=/var/www/env1 python-path=/var/www/env1/mysite threads=5


    #Pointing wsgi script to config file
    WSGIScriptAlias /mysite /var/www/env1/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite
  #Your static files location

  Alias /mysite/media/ "/var/www/env1/mysite/media/"
  Alias /mysite/static/ "/var/www/env1/mysite/static/"
     <Location "/static">
        SetHandler None
   </Location>

<Location "/media">
        SetHandler None
   </Location>
<LocationMatch "\.(jpg|gif|png|js|css)$">
       SetHandler None
   </LocationMatch>


   <Directory /var/www/env1/mysite >
       WSGIProcessGroup mysite
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
   </Directory>



</VirtualHost>
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I may have not read your answer very carefully.
If you do not want to use subdomains you might consider using the django sites framework:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/.

It is a quite cleaner, but more complex solution.